# What is the better practice of hyperledger peers...?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I Just start my customized hyperledger  composer network with 3 organizations. Each organization is include 1 peers(total 3 peers). My question is

1. What is the use of more than one peers in single organization...???
2. What is the best practice to follow the number of organization and number of peer in production level...???

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Fabric : 1.1.0

Composer: 0.19.16

node :8.11.3

Os: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple peers per org provide increased resilience (via redundancy) as well as improved throughput under load. You can start your network with a single peer and add more later. However, in a production system, you would typically want some resilience, and therefore at least 2 endorsing peers per org.

The same goes for the orderer. You would typically use [Kafka](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/kafka.html) for production to provide improved throughput and resilience.

Also, unless you have a strong reason for using Fabric 1.1, you should be at least using 1.2, which is supported by Composer and has [several new features](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/whatsnew.html).

Comment: If you're talking about using Hyperledger Explorer, as long as you configure it accordingly, you will be able to see all channels.

Comment: Actually i need to know creating public block explorer for network as private(Permisionised) is secure.. Please  give your opinion. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can configure Hyperledger Explorer to connect to whatever peers and channels you want. In that way, if you are using multiple channels, you can control what it sees.